# Unable to set hidden field value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hidden-field

I have defined a hidden filed in aspx:-

```
<asp:HiddenField runat ="server" ID="hfBrand" value = "False" />
```

A combo-box control is calling a JavaScript function function:-

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="Brands" runat="server"  
                onclientselectedindexchanged="LoadProperties"
                AutoPostBack="True">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

In that function , I am trying to set that hidden field value to "True":-

```
function LoadProperties(sender, eventArgs)
{ 
var lblBrand = document.getElementById('<%= hfBrand.ClientID %>').value;
alert(lblBrand);
document.getElementById('<%= hfBrand.ClientID %>').value = "True";
alert(lblBrand)
}
```

**QUESTION**:- I can't set the hidden field value to TRUE. WHY it so?? and How to do that?

UPDATE:-
Here is the solution which got me right desired output:-

```
var lblBrand = document.getElementById('<%= hfBrand.ClientID %>').value;
alert(lblBrand);
lblBrand = "True";
alert (lblBrand);
```

Thnx to everyone who helped me.

Comment: did the alert show up or not ?

Comment: Does it hit your alerts correctly and if so what are the outputs..

Also do you have the html that it outputted for the hiddenfield and the javascript function once complete?

Comment: @Aristos -  Both the time alert came. But with values 'False'.

Comment: @Steve - HTML source code I can get. But the problem is why a simple value field is not changing.

Comment: show function LoadProperties from source page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second alert is not referring to the hidden values new value. lblBrand  value doesnt change after you have updated the hfBrand input value

```
function LoadProperties(sender, eventArgs)
{ 
var lblBrand = document.getElementById('<%= hfBrand.ClientID %>');
alert(lblBrand.value);
document.getElementById('<%= hfBrand.ClientID %>').value = "True";
alert(lblBrand.value)
}
```

Try this code!

I reckon it is setting it and you need to get the value of the input again...

(if you wanna see the change, just temporarily change your hidden input to a normal textbox

Comment: You type it faster :) so keep yours, this is the bug here, the alert show the same value.

Comment: @steve and Aristos--- if it sets to 'TRUE' successfully, How would I make it sure. As I have to use this value in server side for some validation. Plz help

Comment: In the second alert use `alert(document.getElementById('<%= hfBrand.ClientID %>').value);`

Comment: The code I put above should alert out the new value of the hidden textbox.

Or use chromes inspect element (or equivalent in ie/firefox) and simply look at the value

Comment: @Steve - yes. you guidance to correct approach helped. thnx a lot.